# Storing the string in run time in C

Tags: c

I am trying to store a string at run time.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

    void main()
    {

       char string[4];
       printf("Enter the String\n");
       scanf("%s", &string[4]);
       printf("The String entered is %s\t", string);
    }
```

Output:
Enter the String
ABCD
The String entered is

But Actual Expected output should be The String entered is ABCD. Why i am getting Empty.

Comment: `char string[5];`... `scanf("%4s", string);`

Comment: `&string[4]` -> `string`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&string[4]` is the address of the end of the the array, not the start of it.

Change it to

```
scanf("%s", string);
```

And if you want to hold 4 chars, you need to make it at least with size = 5 (last one is the null termination character):

```
char string[5];
```

Answer (score 2):

`&string[4]` is one past the end of the array just use `string` to refer to the beginning of the array.

you also should leave space at the end to put a null termination character.